# How to change the color of the green background present when compiling apps using Emscripten-qt (behind the window)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, emscripten

I am using Emscripten-qt to compile Native Qt apps into Javascript.   The application is simple and works fine.  The only problem I am having is that  the   Canvas  has a green background that displays behind the Window.   I want to know how I can change that green background to a different color in order to stick with my color scheme.

[image: Screen shot showing the ugly green background on the right]

Thanks..

mike